# O365 Sharepoint integrated with on prem SSRS

Tags: office-365, reporting-services, sharepoint-server

I have been asked to look for products that help in the connectivity/ integration of our executive O365.SharePoint portal and our SSRS on prem infrastructure.    Looking for products to solve that

I was asked to edit the above to be more specific but I think its pretty much to the point but let see hos this goes.

We need to be able to office a secure tunnel from our corporate SharePoint site which our executive will access.  They will be looking for SSRS reports that are generated, live or are executed within our firewall .  The ability to provide a secure transport in and out without any notice or interaction required by the executive is the ask.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this product, but it looks like it will connect to your on-prem SSRS and display reports in SharePoint Online.

https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104381900?tab=Overview